# Mac terminal - Displaying file permission when changing directory

Tags: permission

When I change a directory in terminal, the output is displaying the write permissions I have for every file in that destination folder. I'd prefer this didn't happen.

[image]

I assume there is something i need to tweak in my bash_profile, but have yet to locate it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can find your bash_profile using: `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Please post the (redacted - if necessary) content of your .bash_profile which is a invisible file in your home directory: `cat ~/.bash_profile`! To save its content to a txt file on your desktop use `cat ~/.bash_profile > ~/Desktop/profilecontent.txt`.

Comment: Here's a link to the whole profile 
http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/649166/bash.txt

Comment: @LvcasX1 Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have access to my bash_profile, I'm just unclear as what to set to avoid the permissions popping up.